# Why does Skein use an output transform, but other similar hashes don't?

Tags: hash, skein

Skein uses an additional compression function call to finalize the output, even when the output isn't larger than the native output size.

The Skein paper says:

> Due to Skein’s output transformation, it remains an open problem how to create collisions or second preimages for the Skein hash function, even if one can create pseudo-collisions or pseudo-second-preimages for the compression function.

and

> **Output transformation.** Originally we applied the output transformation only if the output size
>   was larger than the state size. Unfortunately, without the output transform, you can construct two messages $M$ and $M'$ such that $H(M) ⊕ H(M')$ is the same as the XOR of the last blocks of $M$ and $M'$. (A similar property has recently been described for SHA-1 [101].) This violates the requirement that the hash function behave like a random mapping.

At a high level Blake has a very similar construction but doesn't use such an expensive finalization. Is there a technical reason why Skein needs such a finalization, but Blake doesn't? In particular does the non randomness issue that Skein prevents with the output transform exist in Blake? Why (not)? Is it related to the way Skein turns a blockcipher into a compression function?

Comment: Part of the answer might be that the block-cipher in blake has twice the hash-size, whereas in skein they're equal.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for designing a cryptographic hash function using an
output transformation is flexibility. In the following, I try to
motivate the need for an output transformation.

For example, SHA-256 has no output transformation and a fixed
output size of 256-bit. What happens if you truncate a SHA-256 hash
value? In this case, there are no security claims at all. If something
goes wrong it is YOUR fault, since you have used SHA-256 in an
unspecified mode.

However, the designers of Skein claim the following levels of security
against standard attacks: preimage $2^m$, collision resistance
$2^{m/2}$, where m is the minimum of state and output size.  It is
safe to claim this, as long as the compression and output
transformation are secure. It is hard to claim such a level of
security without an output transformation.

Another problem is the full domain hash (FDH). Assume you are using an
FDH based on RSA-2048. You want to sign messages of arbitrary
length. For the sake of performance, you first have to hash and then
sign the hash values. If your hash value is smaller then 2048-bit you
need a secure padding.  To avoid this, Skein allows to invoke the
output transformation multiple times. In our case you will 
call the output transformation -- over and over again -- until you have 
an 2048-bit hash value.

Comment: Your arguments are not convincing to me. The last paragraph only applies to output sizes larger than the natural output size. You don't explain why truncation requires an output transform. I'm pretty sure it doesn't. Skein's extra features and the use of an output transform for short outputs are orthogonal, as far as I can see.

Comment: You do not need any output transformation at all. :-) In the case of SKEIN, the authors claim the following: "Originally we applied the output transformation only if the output size was larger than the state size. Unfortunately, without the output transform, you can construct two messages M and M' such that H(M) xor H(M) is the same as the XOR of the last blocks of M and M . (A similar property has recently been described for SHA-1
[101].) This violates the requirement that the hash function behave like a random mapping." -- The Skein Hash Function Family, Version 1.3.

Comment: I already quoted that section in my question. But I don't know why Skein without output transform has this property, and other hash functions constructed from a blockcipher with counter do not.